# Type 'ASP._Page_Views__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After publishing my app to a remote host, I start getting this error message.
Locally it works fine and it's been working fine on the remote server before. most definitely  it's an update i made.
Any suggestion?

Similar posts suggested having the Viewstart on the view folder. it's always been there and i never moved it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a publishing issue , maybe a missing file or something like that.
I published the same project again and it worked perfectly